# No Module name Yum in Ansible Error on vagrant

Tags: vagrant, ansible, yum

I was trying out some experiments with Ansible playbooks on Ubuntu Vagrant machine. I have written a simple playbook named exampleyum.yml as follows:

```
---
- hosts: local

  tasks:
    - name: Installing packages
      yum: name=httpd state=latest
      sudo: yes
```

When I run

```
ansible-playbook -i ~/inventory.ini exampleyum.yml
```

I am getting below error:

> An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full
>   traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ImportError: No module named yum
>   fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true,
>   "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n   File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_qeXrGO/ansible_module_yum.py\", line 25, in \n 
>   import yum\nImportError: No module named yum\n", "module_stdout": "",
>   "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"}

It gives some import error and module failure. I read somewhere that `Yum` is a core module

and hence it should work properly, but it doesn't. Any help would be appreciated. I am pretty new to Ansible.

Comment: You could use the "package" command instead of apt / yum in Ansible: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/package_module.html, it will detect what package manager you have already installed (doesn't make a lot of sense to try to use yum on ubuntu)

Comment: I was not aware of "package" command. Thanks @BrunoB.Carvalh for letting me know. That helps. Currently, I am locked out of asking more questions. Can you please upvote my questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am running Ansible on Ubuntu Vagrant machine.

So why do you use `yum` and not `apt` module first of all?

If you still need `yum` module for some reason, ensure that `yum` python package is installed on the managed host.

Comment: Thank you but I wanted to use Yum module, and not apt module. I have installed yum python package, but it still doesnt seem to work. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html

Comment: Yum is the package manager for RedHat-family distros.  Apt is the package manager for Debian-family distros.  Ubuntu is a Debian-family distro.  You should use apt on Ubuntu.  You will need to provide a compelling reason as to why you can't do that.

Comment: Thanks, @XiongChiamiov. I was trying out with yum. It was naive of me. I didn't look for other options like 'apt' or 'package'. They work fine now. Currently, I am locked out of asking more questions. Can you please upvote my question?

Answer (score 0):

Use package instead of yum module as answered in [How to unify package installation tasks in ansible?](https://serverfault.com/questions/587727/how-to-unify-package-installation-tasks-in-ansible) in the playbook.

I had the same error when I read and followed a book which was written based on CentOS/RedHat. The issue itself can be avoided as below, but it would cause further issues if keep using YUM on Ubuntu.

### Environment

```
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
```

### Confirmation of the symptom

```
ansible@ip-172-31-38-30:~/playbook$ ansible-playbook sample.yaml -v
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [ub01]

TASK [Ensure NTP (for time synchronization) is installed.] *********************
fatal: [ub01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to ub01 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_y0ULtJ/ansible_module_yum.py\", line 25, in <module>\r\n    import yum\r\nImportError: No module named yum\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/ansible/playbook/sample.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
ub01                       : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

### Install yum

```
ansible@ip-172-31-38-30:~/playbook$ sudo apt install yum
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  yum
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 58 not upgraded.
Need to get 486 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,265 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 yum all 3.4.3-3 [486 kB]
Fetched 486 kB in 0s (12.3 MB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package yum.
(Reading database ... 110977 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/yum_3.4.3-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking yum (3.4.3-3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up yum (3.4.3-3) ...
```

### Verify the original issue is gone

```
ansible@ip-172-31-38-30:~/playbook$ ansible-playbook sample.yaml -v
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [ub01]

TASK [Ensure NTP (for time synchronization) is installed.] *********************
fatal: [ub01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "No package matching 'ntp' found available, installed or updated", "rc": 126, "results": ["No package matching 'ntp' found available, installed or updated"]}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/ansible/playbook/sample.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
ub01                       : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

### Related Issue

The location of the python can be the cause for Ansible and Yum.

- [How do I handle python pathing not having a Python 2.X in /usr/bin/python on a remote machine?](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-handle-python-pathing-not-having-a-python-2-x-in-usr-bin-python-on-a-remote-machine)

Note too that /usr/bin/yum refers to /usr/bin/python.

```
#! /usr/bin/python 
import sys
try:
    import yum
except ImportError:
    print >> sys.stderr, """\
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:
```